# Deleting like elements in two vectors C++

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I am trying to search two vectors (each of any size) for elements that are identical and then delete both elements.

My implementation is as follows:

```
for (int i = vec1.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     for (int j = 0; j < vec2.size(); j++) {
          if (vec1[i] == vec2[j]) {
             vec1.erase(vec1.begin() + i);
             vec2.erase(vec2.begin() + j);
          }
     }
}
```

However, while this works for most cases, I am running into some where it doesn't. Is it the way I am iterating through these vectors or am I just going about this all wrong?

Comment: Are you allowed to sort both vectors to achieve your goal?

Comment: Sorting is the key here

Comment: What happens if `vec1` has `[1,2,2,3]` and `vec2` has `[2]`? Do you expect both `2`s in `vec1` to be removed?

Comment: I can sort if needed. Only pairs(vec1[i], vec2[j]) need to be deleted, if the value is repeated again in the same vector, it can be left alone.

Comment: What are some examples where it doesn't work? Also I notice that you're iterating backwards for `vec1` but forwards for `vec2`. That could have some issues.

Comment: This is being used to simplify fractions. vec1 holds the prime factorization of the numerator and vec2 holds the prime factorization of the denominator. It is crashing my program when I try to simplify 2/8 or 2/16. Those are the two I have found so far.

Comment: So, for 2 / 8, vec1 = {2}, vec2 = {2, 2, 2}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to iterate backwards at all. In which case your code can be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec1.size(); i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < vec2.size(); j++) {
          if (vec1[i] == vec2[j]) {
             vec1.erase(vec1.begin() + i);
             vec2.erase(vec2.begin() + j);
          }
     }
}
```

But wait up...what happens after we erase an element? Then all of the elements after it have their indexes decreased by 1, so we'll skip the next item! To fix that we can add this small modification:

```
             vec1.erase(vec1.begin() + i--);
             vec2.erase(vec2.begin() + j--);
                                       ^^^^
```

This will work even when we change the size by erasing, because we're checking the size of the `vec2` every loop! But what if we end up erasing the last item of `vec1`? We don't compare its size again until we've iterated *all* the way through `vec2`, which will be a problem in your `vec1 = {2}, vec2 = {2, 2, 2}` example. To fix that we can just break out of the inner loop and repeat the check on `vec2`.

Put it all together (and change your subscript operator into `.at()` calls so we'll have bounds checking) and you get:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec1.size(); i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < vec2.size(); j++) {
          if (vec1.at(i) == vec2.at(j)) {
             vec1.erase(vec1.begin() + i--);
             vec2.erase(vec2.begin() + j--);
             break;
          }
     }
}
```

(See it in action here: [ideone](https://ideone.com/f9eGUp))

Comment: That's not an underflow.  It's converted to -1 when assigned to an int.

Comment: I believe it's undefined behavior to assign an unsigned value to an int if it doesn't fit.

Comment: @SidS It is underflow, but you're right, `int` will interpret it as `-1`, I'm thinking if he was using it as a comparison ie: `vec1.size() - 1 > 5`...editing now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you keep accessing `vec1[i]` as you loop over `vec2` after deleting an element from `vec1` and `vec2`. This causes undefined behavior if you do this after removing the last element in `vec1` as `vec1[i]` is no longer valid. Add a `break` statement in your `if` to fix this.

```
for (int i = vec1.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     for (int j = 0; j < vec2.size(); j++) {
          if (vec1[i] == vec2[j]) {
             vec1.erase(vec1.begin() + i);
             vec2.erase(vec2.begin() + j);
             break; // Look at next element in vec1
          }
     }
}
```

There's also a more efficient way of doing this too (`O(n*log(n)+m*log(m)+n+m)` instead of `O(n*m)` for `n=vec1.size()` and `m=vec2.size()`). It involves sorting the vectors. I'll leave that to you to figure out.

Comment: This worked perfectly for 2/8 and 2/16. I am going to do some more testing though. Thanks so much, man!

Comment: `O(n+m)`? Wouldn't sorting them already take at least `O(nlog(n)+mlog(m))`? Unless you're thinking something like bucket sort, but that would mean limiting the range of numbers given.

Answer (score 1):

If you can sort, you could do something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

  std::vector<int> ex {3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5}, as {2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1}, tmp;

  std::sort(std::begin(ex), std::end(ex));
  std::sort(std::begin(as), std::end(as));

  as.erase(
    std::remove_if(
      std::begin(as),std::end(as),
      [&](int const& s){
        bool found = std::binary_search(std::begin(ex), std::end(ex), s);
        if (found) {
          tmp.push_back(s);
        }
        return found;}), std::end(as));
  for (auto const& i : tmp) {
    ex.erase(std::remove(std::begin(ex),std::end(ex), i), std::end(ex));
  }

}
```

Comment: This removes from one vector but not the other. Calling `erase` on the other vector after won't work since the first vector was already modified.

Comment: Agreed. Fixing as I write.

Comment: Fixed solution. Works tested.

Comment: Does this remove duplicates? I think OP wants `vec1={2}` and `vec2={2,2,2}` to give `vec1={}` and `vec2={2,2}`.

Comment: It removes duplicates in both. Just play around with it a little.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `std::set_difference` to subtract one vector from another and them merge these subtractions with a help of `std::merge`. But vectors need to be sorted to use these functions, so use `std::sort` at first. Code is here:

```
void TraceVector( std::vector<int> v, const std::string& title )
{
    if ( !title.empty() )
    {
        std::cout << title << std::endl;
    }

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    std::vector<int> Vec1 {7, 1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 8, 9};
    std::vector<int> Vec2 {3, 2, 5, 7, 10};
    std::vector<int> Difference1; // Contains subtraction Vec1 - Vec2
    std::vector<int> Difference2;// Contains subtraction Vec2 - Vec1
    std::vector<int> Merged; // RESULT Merged vector after subtractions

    //Need to be sorted
    std::sort(Vec1.begin(), Vec1.end());
    std::sort(Vec2.begin(), Vec2.end());

    TraceVector(Vec1, "Vec1 sorted is: ");
    TraceVector(Vec2, "Vec2 sorted is: ");

    //Make subtractions
    std::set_difference(Vec1.begin(), Vec1.end(), Vec2.begin(), Vec2.end(),
                        std::inserter(Difference1, Difference1.begin()));
    std::set_difference(Vec2.begin(), Vec2.end(), Vec1.begin(), Vec1.end(),
                        std::inserter(Difference2, Difference2.begin()));


    TraceVector(Difference1, "Difference is: ");
    TraceVector(Difference2, "Difference is: ");

    //Merge subtrctions
    std::merge(Difference1.begin(), Difference1.end(), Difference2.begin(), Difference2.end(), back_inserter(Merged));
    TraceVector(Merged, "Merged is: ");
}
```

Output is:

```
Vec1 sorted is: 
1,2,5,5,5,7,8,9,
Vec2 sorted is: 
2,3,5,7,10,
Difference is: 
1,5,5,8,9,
Difference is: 
3,10,
Merged is: 
1,3,5,5,8,9,10,
Program ended with exit code: 0
```